# How can I expose my APEX app to the web in the Autonomous Database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I am using an Autonomous Database that has private endpoints. The APEX apps on this database are not accessible on the internet as a result. How can I expose my apps to the web?

Disclaimer: I am a product manager for Autonomous Database.

Answer (score 1):

Today, APEX is subject to the access controls set for your database. So, if the database is using private endpoints and it is not exposed to the internet, that means APEX also cannot be accessed from the internet.

To expose APEX to the web in this case, you can [install your own ORDS mid-tier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/ords-customer-managed.html#GUID-1094A25C-44C3-4912-8DB2-6413B7973D9B) and expose that to the internet. Another option is to [configure a load balancer of your own](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/introducing-vanity-urls-on-adb) and expose that to the web. This latter option also provides the ability to use vanity URLs of your choosing instead of the default APEX URLs that come with the database.

Disclaimer: I am a product manager for Autonomous Database.